# Is it possible to report some of my reporters after every iteration, and a few at the end of the entire run in NetLogo via BehaviourSpace?

Tags: netlogo

I want to report a bunch of reporters via behaviour space in Netlogo, but not all of them after every iteration. How can I report a couple of them at the end of each run, i.e. when max time is reached, so that they are recorded in the csv file for the last iteration only? Otherwise the run time becomes too long if I report them after every iteration.